# What kind of database the Sql Server Migration Assistant uses as an internal data repository?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-migration-assi

What kind of database the Sql Server Migration Assistant uses as an internal data repository and stores it in the source-metabase.mb file?

I guess that this it is one of standard tool that I could use to open and edit some entries (I need to autamatically add some custom scripts for tables with BLOBs data migration )

You could also just suggest the way how to check most popular database formats: SqlServer Compact, MySQL, Access..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is one of standard tool that I could use to open and edit some entries

I would not count on it :) It was a proprietary metadata format that has nothing to do with DB products that SSMA supports. It can store metadata for representing Oracle and also SQL Server among others, obviously formats are not connected with file structure that actual DBs use. SSMA format has no open docs, also it may fail to synchronize your changes after manual intervention if you reverse engineer it (due to the fact it was designed just as the migration tool to target SQL Server and was supposed to mostly create new objects there based on source database counterparts).

Can you just write some stored procedures or triggers in your database? For most DBs metadata is exposed as special tables/views anyway. Probably you need to do it only for SQL Server as it's your target db after migration, right? Looking into ways to directly parse or manipulate files managed by "big" DB  (like SQL Server or Oracle) doesn't seem to be a good idea for most scenarios. (except digital forensics, for example)

SQL Server metadata related views are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) and functions are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187812.aspx). You may profile your SQL Server instance while connecting to it with SSMA just to get some feel what it does to extract metadata (object names, columns of tables, source of SPs etc.)

Data manipulation is pretty much clear from the DB side if you need it too.

Comment: What I want - to automatize data import (not to manipulate  metadata of source db). The only one step that I can't automatize is to create "custom data migration scripts" for some tables (some big table blobs should be imported with empty values, not with real blobs)... And yes I can create 'view' on the source side, you are right, but I do not see how it could help to configure ssma xml-scripts, data migration section.

Comment: In any way your information is very important. If SSMA uses 'proprietary metadata format' then it is much more simpler for me to create my own data import procedures for several tables. Of course not so powrefull (ssma some how use Bulk insert on the fly) but still should work for me...

Comment: I didn't work with SSMA for quite a while and my knowledge can be outdated, but... SSMA was much more advanced in the area of metadata conversion (e.g. converting stored procedures from PL/SQL to T-SQL), and the data migration is covered for straightforward cases mostly. There are other tools to perform advanced data migration too - maybe SSIS is better for your task? Probably worth creating a more specific question about data migration in your case then, just to make sure people will suggest other data migration solutions than SSMA

Comment: I mentioned system tables/views because supposed you need to manipulate metadata somehow, not just data. Or at least identify objects that have specific type of column etc. For pure data migration task it's not so useful.

Comment: SSMA didn't pull data to its saved files, otherwise it would have to download huge amount of data on the machine running SSMA. ~2008 versions of SSMA used bulk copy to migrate data from source DB to target DB directly (not even involving your computer running SSMA to pump data). So parsing/changing SSMA project files is not helpful to get to the actual data. You could create a similar ad hoc tool, bulk copy is documented [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Still would prefer an existing solution if possible.

Comment: Me too allways prefer existing. That is why I have started this topic :)